# How to solve macro cannot be found VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I made a vba to run through a few macros in a sequence.

I assigned a button to a macro which will start the sequence.

```
Sub mixerStarter()

Call PrimaryDataGet
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Call ValueSetter
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
Call dataShift
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "mixerMiddle()"

End Sub


Sub mixerMiddle()
Call PrimaryDataGet
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Call dataShift
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
End sub
```

The `mixerStarter` runs perfectly but as soon as it hits `mixerMiddle` I get an error message saying

[image: Error message]

All macros are in module 1

As a recommendation from another question of a similar nature, I deleted all underscores from the names of my macros

What to do ?

Comment: Are you having the `End Sub` at the end of the macro? (it seems to be missing ....)

Comment: There's a lot of different ways to call a macro, maybe you can try one of these more specific ones, that gives the workbook name + the macro in this tutorial: https://exceloffthegrid.com/how-to-run-a-macro-from-another-workbook/
Other than that, Do you have an End Sub on mixerMiddle? in your code example, it's not there, and that would be an error.

Comment: Just remove the brackets

Comment: @Luuk Thanks for pointing it out but I had the 'End sub' but I must have skipped it while copying. I have added it to the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedure in `OnTime` doesn't take brackets, so use:

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "mixerMiddle"
```

instead.

Ref:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime

Comment: You were right. I scratched my head out searching for why excel was giving me that error. Thank you so much !!!